# Primefaces Fileupload Patch

Tags: jsf, patch, primefaces

I have the same problem as the guy in [this](http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4018) post.

Can you help me apply the patch from [here](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=963#c10)

I have no idea if that solves it, but I will try if you can tell me how to apply a patch :-)

Answer (score 1):

PrimeFaces uses [Apache Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) (SVN) as code repository. It's available [here](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/checkout). If you configure your development tool to connect to this code repository (e.g. Eclipse has a Subclipse plugin for this), then you can hook on it, download the entire project, apply the patch yourself and then rebuild the project into a JAR file yourself.

This should be pretty straightforward if you're already familiar with code repositories like CVS, Git, Mercurial, etc. An alternative is to wait for them to release a new version so that you can just download the ready-to-use JAR from their side.

Comment: alright didn't thought about building the jar myself, but why not :-)