# How can I apply PrimeFaces's patch in NetBeans 7.0.1

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, primefaces, patch

I ran into the `NumberFormatException` which was [reported](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1720) as a bug of PrimeFaces v2.2.1. Someone provided a patch for that bug but I have no idea how I can apply it to the built-in PrimeFaces of my NetBeans 7.0.1.

I'd be very grateful if someone could show me how I can apply the patch.

Comment: Have you resolved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at this: [Primefaces Fileupload Patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802429/primefaces-fileupload-patch)

though, you see that `cagatay.civici` says: `You should not update a schedule with PPR, it has it's own update api to be used instead.` (which works fine).

So what can you do is:

- Update to Primefaces 3.0.M4
- Try to apply that patch
- Check if you have the latest Primefaces 2 version
- Contact the guy who implemented that patch, because as you can see there, the email is provided(hoping that is real)